# How to complete a milestone on GitHub?

Tags: github, milestone

How do I close/complete milestones on GitHub projects? I've already three milestones that are "overdue" but they are completed already. I simply don't know how to mark them "completed" - can anyone help me?

I already tried to Google this issue, and browsed the GitHub help pages, but couldn't find any information on using milestones.

Comment: When all issues of the milestone are closed, the milestone should be closed as well.

Comment: And if there were no issues for a certain milestone, should i simply create one to close the milestone?

Comment: If you are looking for milestones, then goto to Issues and click on Milestones next to the new issue button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Milestones are only closed manually. You can close a milestone by clicking the "close" link in the list of milestones. Note that for some reason, there is no "close" button in the milestone's details page, only in the list page of milestones.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For those wondering how to get to this page in the first place, it's "Issues" or "Pull Requests".

Comment: For those who are just beginning and who wonder how to get the milestone to 100 % or whatever percentage: create issues and assign them to an existing milestone. As soon as you close an issue, its share in the total number of issues of that milestone will be shown by the green bar.

Answer (score 27):

**Update**: this is an old answer for an old question. The nowerdays correct answer is the one by [seeker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25554654/1260906).

**Milestones now must be closed manually.** --- [A.J. Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264016/a-j-brown)

---

Simply creating and closing an issue for a milestone, will mark the milestone completed:

> When all issues of the milestone are closed, the milestone should be closed as well.

--- [Felix King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

Thanks.

Comment: This used to happen reliably, but isn't happening for me anymore. Any clues? Milestone shows 100% completed

Comment: What's wrong? With the new Github layout a milestone still completes when all issues related to the milestone are closed/fixed.

Comment: The only thing wrong is that the milestone no longer closes for me, I need to go and close it manually. Seems to have started around the time of the new layout.

Comment: You need to connect the issues to the milestone. It's working here. Anyways, there is a `close` button now for milestones.

Comment: I don't see how I've been unclear. Whereas milestones used to close when the last issue in the milestone was closed, now, even when I close the last open issue in the milestone, the milestone remains open, and I have to close it manually. Notice the '100% completed' in my first comment.

Answer (score 16):

One way of interpreting the GitHub blog post [Simpler Milestone Workflow](https://github.com/blog/1536-simpler-milestone-workflow) is that Milestone state change via issues was disabled with the update on June 18, 2013:

> Milestones will no longer change state based on any sort of issue assignment.

Edit: I contacted GitHub support regarding this, and they confirmed that it is indeed the intended behaviour.

Comment: Wow, didn't know we could close milestones that way.